# Elm - Update date input field from js does not work

Tags: javascript, elm

I'm working on a project with elm, but currently I'm stuck on the following problem:  I want to update a generated input field from elm

```
newDate address =
    header
      [ id "header" ]
      [ input
          [ id "datePicker"
          , autofocus False
          , type' "date"
          , onEnter address Add
          ]
          []
      ]
```

My initial thought was to integrate my .elm code with html, which I succeeded doing so, to enable me to create custom js scripts to interact with the dom.

However, when adding the following script (to put the date to the current day) it does not seem to update the date field.

```
    $(document).ready( function() {
        var now = new Date();

        var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
        var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);

        var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day) ;

        $('#datePicker').val(today);
    });
```

But, if I execute this code in the browser console itself, it does work.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

-K

added : on request the elm integration into html

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Embedded Elm</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="elm.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>

    <body>
        <div id="main" style="width:50%; height:400px;"></div>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var mainDiv = document.getElementById('main');
    Elm.embed(Elm.Main, mainDiv);

    $(document).ready( function() {
        var now = new Date();

        var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
        var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);

        var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day) ;
       $('#datePicker').val(today);
    });


    </script>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you please share how you're including both this script and the elm application in your html? I am guessing that the script works, but that the dom ready event is fired before the elm application renders for the first time.

Comment: For me it is running ok in Chrome but not in Firefox. I guess your JS is running before the form gets in DOM.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that my initial instinct is accurate, i.e the behaviour of `Elm.embed` is more asynchronous than we would perhaps like, and the `ready` callback is firing before the element is present within the DOM. It would be worth observing the sequence of events in the debugger to verify this is the case.

**Edit**: Having just had a quick look myself, it *looks* like the first elm frame may be rendered synchronously by the call to `embed`. Are you confident that your application's initial state results in that form component's inclusion?

In any case, if what you want to achieve is to initialise the field *once* with the current date, this question might be useful: [Initialize model with current date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34380495/initialize-model-with-current-date)

**Edit 2**: One other thing that could be causing some issues is including the `<script>` tag *after* the `<body>` tag closes. This question seems to suggest that is not a great idea; perhaps you could also try including it before `<body>` is closed?